# Possible "not a question" post

Tags: discussion

Recently, someone posted the question "[Fee surcharge for international students](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/8565/73)", which was an undisguised rant. Someone mentioned this in the comments, and the user tacked on a question. To me, the question as added is likely off-topic here; it's a legal question about academia, not an academic question. However, the fact that the question was tacked on as such indicates to me that the user is looking more for discussion than an answer. I would vote to close, but my vote is automatically binding, so I wanted to see what the community thought. Do you think this question should be closed as "not a real question"?

Comment: You might think of this as a rant. However, there are few avenues where I can get any input on this matter. acad.SE could probably provide me with input from various academicians from different countries. And I don't think it is a rant because I clearly note in the question that I am unsure if this is a fair or unfair measure by the university.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that this as it stands this is not really a question. There might be one in there, but it is pretty buried. I am also think the question has a strong personal bias.

As for not using your mod powers, I think you are correct. We now have a fair number of users who can and do vote to close. I like thye idea of letting the community decide and bringing attention to possible questions with meta/chat like you did here.

Comment: I completely agree with your answer, there might an interesting question, but it also looks a lot like a rant (which I can understand, but here is not the place to rant). I also think it's good to bring such cases to meta, and I'll try to do it more in the future.

Comment: To be fair to @Charles, it was his idea for me to post this here. Credit where credit is due and all :)

Answer (score 1):

I did not vote to close this question simply because I was in the OP's shoes many years ago.

Personally I am on the OP's side. However, I believe this question is solicting opinions and could stir up endless debates, not suitable for our site.

It is more about public government policies than just academic one. If it is a decision made by state government, how do you overrule it?

For example, every state university in the US I know of impose tuition charges on in-state residents and out-of-state residents differently. From in-state resident's position, this is fair. Out-of-state residents feel this policy is unfair. Endless debate.

Thanks to those who voted to close. Save me a lot struggle.