# Are questions about a university counselors on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a problem/question about a university counselor who seems to be unprofessional to me. I'd like to ask about it on academia stack exchange. Will it be on-topic?

Comment: What is your question, in particular? How is this question different than "I do not get along with a co-worker/boss?" that occurs in every workplace, inside and outside academia? If the question is more focused on why this particular question is academic in nature, I believe it will be on topic for the academia.se.

Answer (score 7):

In general, such questions are on-topic, as they clearly relate to academic life. However, you have to consider the following:

- The individuals concerned should not be identifiable from your post. See also: [Should we name names when talking about bad publishers and researchers?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1297/7734)
- You should ask a question that you can reasonably expect to be answerable by us without knowing all your details and that may be helpful to others in a similar situation. In particular your post should not just be a rant. See also these Meta posts:

  - [Do we want questions of the form "My professor is bad. Right?"](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3259/7734)
  - ["Here's my situation, any suggestions?" is not an answerable question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1205/7734)
  - [Time to Expressly Ban "I want to do X, Here's My Life Story..." questions?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1093/7734)